# C# - Default index.cshtml as start page in Web Api .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing a Web API project and I need to deploy it on linux server. The requirements of the load balancer on the server is to have a default page.

For that reason I created a `Home` controller with `Index` action

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("/")]
   [Route("Home/Index")]
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
            return View();
    }
}
```

Change the configure method in startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseMvc();

}
```

Now after these changes if I deploy the app in local `IIS` it works fine and load the default View Home/Index when I access it the URL localhost:801

But If I deploy it on linux it gives a 503 error and there are different errors in the log too

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter[1]  Request successfully
> matched the route with name '(null)' and template ''.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiVersionActionSelector[2]
> Action 'UMD.VAST.WebAPI.Controllers.HomeController.Index
> (UMD.VAST.WebAPI)' with id 'b83c6143-cd71-4847-90e8-14a963a8ce31' did
> not match the constraint
>
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.HttpMethodActionConstraint'
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler[3]  No
> actions matched the current request. Route values:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware[1] Request did not match
> any routes.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DefaultApiVersionRoutePolicy[5]
> Multiple candidate actions were found, but none matched the requested
> service API version '1.0'. Candidate actions:
> UMD.VAST.WebAPI.Controllers.HomeController.Index (UMD.VAST.WebAPI)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object. at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(HttpRequest
> request) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DefaultApiVersionRoutePolicy.ClientError(RouteContext
> context, ActionSelectionResult selectionResult)

Comment: have you tried running running in vs with the production environment? also have you tried checking for errors in the console in the linux server?

Comment: It is working in release and debug mode from visual studio. and in Linux server it says : Request did not match any routes.

Comment: Not just release mode. You need to try in production environment as well. You can copy these existing profiles and create a new profile with `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"`

Comment: regarding the linux where are you seeing the error? not matching routes may also mean it is unable to reach the default error page location. Usually in production environment, it is designed to show the error page in the browser and the list of error logs in the console

Comment: change route to [Route("api/[controller]")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work with `Web API` Controller, but I fixed it by using the MVC Controller for the Index page. Rest of the controller are Web Api controllers.

Code in `Configure` method for MVC routes is

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
      //Home
      routes.MapRoute(
         name: "home",
         template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
  });
```

For Web Api controllers I'm using the attribute routing